# savetrees and natbib can't be used at the same time?

Tags: natbib, incompatibility, savetrees

I am very confused. Look at the simple code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{savetrees}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

    aaa

\end{document}
```

This will return "Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}". If I delete either package, things get normal. But how can I use both packages at the same time?

Comment: Welcome! (If you are wondering how to format the code: one way to do that is to put it in the cursor and press the `{}` button.)

Comment: note that the tex error does _not_ say undefined command `\begin{document}` it shows the undefined command as `\bibitemsep`  If you are using texstudio you are the 100000th person to be confused by [This issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/) and you could leave a note there asking that it be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

[`savetrees`](//ctan.org/pkg/savetrees) adjusts the spacing and font of the elements within the `thebibliography` environment in order to save space (or trees). These include `\bibfont` and `\bibitemsep`. It checks for the existence of `\bibfont`, and if that's true, then it redefines `\bibitemsep` to be virtually non-existent:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifundefined{bibfont}{}{%
    \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}%
    \bibitemsep=0pt plus 2pt\relax
  }%
}%
```

All of the above is done at `\begin{document}`, and that's why the error is thrown there, since [`natbib`](//ctan.org/pkg/natbib) defines a `\bibfont` but no `\bibitemsep`. The fault lies with `savetrees` for assuming only [`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) defines `\bibfont`. However, `natbib` does as well. Here's an excerpt from the [`savetrees` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/savetrees):

> If the `biblatex` package was loaded we use BibLaTeX's mechanisms for reducing the
>   font size to `\small` (`\bibfont`) and for omitting blank lines between bibliographic
>   entries (`\bibitemsep`).

The way around it is to define `\bibitemsep` as a length or a dimen:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\newlength\bibitemsep
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}

% Your masterpiece here...

\end{document}
```